# How do i get values from a combo box?

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox

```
import fl.events.*;  

const PointsStart:int=0;  

var Points:int=PointsStart;  

youChose.text=String(Points)+" points";  

comboBox.prompt='Contestants'  
comboBox.addItem({label:"John Smith",Points:10});  
comboBox.addItem({label:"Chris Tucker",Points:12});  
comboBox.addItem({label:"Paul Allen",Points:14});  

comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, listevalg);  


function listevalg (evt:Event)  
{  
    Points=comboBox.selectedItem.Points;  
    youChose.text=String(Value)+" points";  
}
```

I'd like to have a textbox that says what the current standings are. Say I choose Chris Tucker in the combo box, I want the textbox to say something like 'He's in second place'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know which rank each person is in. To do that you can copy the list of people and sort it by Points, then register their rank as their position in that list.

```
import fl.events.*;  

const PointsStart:int=0;  

var Points:int=PointsStart;  

youChose.text=String(Points)+" points";  

comboBox.prompt='Contestants'  

var people:Array = [{label:"John Smith",Points:10},
                    {label:"Chris Tucker",Points:12},
                    {label:"Paul Allen",Points:14}];

// Copy of "people", sorted by Points, descending.
var sortedPeople:Array = people.concat().sortOn("Points", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);

for each (var person:Object in people) {
    // Register this person's ranking as its position in the sorted array + 1
    // (because indexes start at 0)
    person.Rank = sortedPeople.indexOf(person) + 1;
    comboBox.addItem(person);
}

comboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, listevalg);  


function listevalg (evt:Event)  
{  
    Points=comboBox.selectedItem.Points;
    // The ranking is now available as "item.Rank".
    youChose.text=String(Points)+" points, rank "+String(comboBox.selectedItem.Rank);
}
```

If you don't actually need to keep the current order in the combobox, you don't even need  to make a copy of the array before sorting.

Comment: Thanks, but what part of my code do I change out with this, because now I get all the names listed twice in the combo box. Also it just sys 'rank' in the text field.

Comment: It was supposed to replace the creation and event listener part. I've just updated to show a more complete view of the code. I don't have an IDE right now, so it may contain a few syntax errors, but this is the general direction.

Comment: If you think an answer helped you solve the problem, please don't forget to mark it as Accepted Answer.